# Google Big Query won't let me schedule query

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am an owner of the Google Big Query project and I am trying to setup a schedule query. But it throws me an error as shown on image:

[image: Error]

I have investigated across StackOverflow but nothing works for me. I have tried:

1. Run query first before creating schedule query
2. Choose data location (in my case EU)
3. Verify access permission - I am owner of the project.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Solution found: Client missed billing account.

Answer (score 4):

You will get this `Schedule Query Error` message because of the following reasons:

- If you selected a wrong Dataset location in the `New scheduled query` will throw an error message “Scheduled Query Error”.
- The least possible limit for the scheduled query under custom is 15 minutes. So, if you try scheduling a query by setting a custom time less than every 15 minutes will throw an error message 'Scheduled Query Error'. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries) for more information.
- If your Cron-like time specification syntax is not valid in the Custom schedule field will throw an error message 'Scheduled Query Error'. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?&_ga=2.49083110.-1372970496.1654749553#formatting_the_schedule) for valid formats.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have verified Dataset location and it is correct, it is EU. Also my query will run daily and I am defining schedule query time within BigQuery UI. Is there anything I am doing wrong? It is strange, because within other BigQuery projects schedule queries work like a charm.

Comment: Hi, I have shared all the possibilities to resolve the “Scheduled Query Error”. If you are still facing the same issue, file a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-2). They will inspect your project and let you know.

Comment: The question is closed so I have to comment here: this can happen if your browser blocks popups, as the auth for creating/modifying scheduled queries uses a popup. If it's blocked, you see the 'scheduled query error'  message